# Return Value from JDBC Transaction

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, transactions

Is it possible to return a value from a JDBC transaction? For example, suppose I need to know if the value corresponding to 'key' is 1 or -1 *immediately* after applying the following transaction. Performing a subsequent `SELECT` on the key introduces a race condition, because another concurrent process may execute the same transaction after the first completes but before the subsequent `SELECT` is performed. Is it possible for the transaction to return the value to me?

```
con.setAutoCommit(false)
val stmt = con.createStatement()
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE table SET value = CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END WHERE key = 'key'");
con.commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RETURNING` clause for that. But to be able to process the value from that, you have to use `execute()` instead of `executeUpdate()`

```
con.setAutoCommit(false)
Statement stmt = con.createStatement()
stmt.execute("UPDATE table SET value = CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END WHERE key = 'key' RETURNING value");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
  int key = rs.getInt(1);
  ... do something with that
}
```

Comment: or in one shot `ResultSet result = statement.executeUpdate("query");`, **note** we can we also use `executeUpdate` with `INSERT UPDATE AND DELETE` read more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/statement-object-example.htm)

Comment: @YCF_L: You can not use `executeUpdate()` for queries that return a result. [Quote from the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-): "*Executes the given SQL statement, (...) **that returns nothing***". And the Postgres driver **will** fail with "A result was returned when none was expected" when you use `executeUpdate()` with a query that returns a result.

Comment: i meant `int result = statement.executeUpdate("query");` so if the result is great then 0 mean you have one or more statement executed, else if the result is 0 mean there are no record is updated or inserted or deleted, so i don't see any necessary to use ResultSet

Comment: @YCF_L: The result set is there to get the new value of the column _after_ the update without having to run another SELECT statement. It's not there to check if something was updated at all.